# Excel match multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an excel formula to return a certain value in column E of worksheet1 if the following criteria are fulfilled:

```
-value in column A;row x in worksheet1 matches value in column A;row y in worksheet2
-value in column K;row x in worksheet1 matches value in column C;row y in worksheet2
```

if a match is found, the return value should be the value in column E of worksheet 2 times a certain value in another worksheet (cell B23 in worksheet3 in this case)

images of both worksheets included below
[image: worksheet1]
[image: worksheet2]
so in this case cell L122 of worksheet1 which contains the formula, should return value E6 of worksheet2 (because 05.11. and 'st' are matched)

Formula so far:

```
=INDEX(worksheet2!$E$4:$E$285;match(worksheet1!A1&worksheet1!K1;worksheet2!$A$4:$A$285&worksheet2!$C$4:$C$285;0))*(worksheet3!$B$23/750)
```

but it seems I'm doing something wrong with the match/index formula and not really a clue what causes the formula to fail :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the issue occurs when dragging the formula, my guess is that `worksheet2!C4:C285` is the cause, as you have absolute referencing elsewhere but not here... To be of more help a small example mock up of data with your expected output would really help us to assist you.

Comment: *'return a certain value in E of worksheet3'* doesn't jibe with `worksheet2!$E$4:$E$285`. In fact it is all a little confusing and made more so when the sample formula contradicts the narrative. Can you post expected results?

Comment: updated/corrected my questing with some images and more info.
sorry, made some mistakes in simplifying my data/question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sub>... cell L122 of worksheet1 which contains the formula, should return value E6 of worksheet2 (because 05.11. and 'st' are matched)</sub>

Multiple column matches are simplified somewhat with AGGREGATE. Put this in worksheet1!L122

```
=INDEX(worksheet2!$E$4:$E$285; aggregate(15; 7;
            row($4:$285)/((worksheet2!$A$4:$A$285=worksheet1!A122)*
                          (worksheet2!$C$4:$C$285=worksheet1!K122)); 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this formula doesn't seem to work if I implement it into my excel document, I am not really into the aggregate function, so just to simplify it I created an extra column with the combined search values in worksheet2 and just used the vert.lookup function =vert.lookup(A1&K1; ....

Comment: there seams to be both ; and , used as separator in the function

Comment: Thanks @W_O_L_F, don't how I left it like that.

Comment: Ok, checking those solved my problem.
Thanks! ;) Will do a little bit of research in the Aggregate function and implement it in my file