# Excel match multiple values in one cell to a list of values in a column to then receive a singular sum?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have attached an image (tables listed below) to better explain what I am currently struggling with and am unsure if it is even possible to do with excel so I thought I might ask some proffesionals all help would be much appreciated.

On the far right is a table matching the "A ID"s to a list of "B ID"s which are all placed in a singular cell.
I need to match these IDs to the columns on the left and produce a sum from the "B Values" in the "Grouped Value" column based on the "A ID"s.

A numerical explanation would be that in the "Grouped values" column in row 2 which would be "A ID" 1 (cell F2) I need it to display the sum of all corresponding "B values" based on their "IDs", which would be 25(111),75(112) and 400 (113).

The formula would need to produce F2= 500, F3= 700, F4= 485

The difficulties I run into is that there is a different number of "B ID"s for each "A ID".

Ex. "A ID" 1 has 3 corresponding "B IDS" whilst "A ID" 3 has 5.

I must add this is a test sheet and the actual list of numbers are much more extensive and have no clear structure for both ID types.The only categorisation present is a table such as the one on the right hand side.

Thank you again for any help.

Unable to figure out the grouping of matching single cells to multiple cells within a column I tried using Vlookup, index and match.

| A ID | B ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 112 113 |
| 2 | 221 222 223 224 |
| 3 | 331 332 333 334 335 |

| A ID | B ID | B Value | Grouped Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 25 |  |
| 2 | 112 | 75 |  |
| 3 | 113 | 400 |  |
|  | 221 | 30 |  |
|  | 222 | 70 |  |
|  | 223 | 250 |  |
|  | 224 | 350 |  |
|  | 331 | 100 |  |
|  | 332 | 35 |  |
|  | 333 | 40 |  |
|  | 334 | 60 |  |
|  | 335 | 250 |  |

Comment: Have you considered sumif() or sumifs()?

Comment: Instead of amn image, post some data so we can copy and paste. Having to type in your data to help you is boring.

Comment: John have you refer to any of the related questions and answers on site? for e.g. start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463955/in-excel-sum-all-values-in-one-column-in-each-row-where-another-column-is-a-spe?rq=2) and [lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647482/excel-match-multiple-values?rq=2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula in E2:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$13)*(ISNUMBER(FIND($G$2:$G$13,$B2 & " "))))`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For, AFAIK, all versions of Excel:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&E$2:E$13&" "," "&B2&" "))*F$2:F$13)
```

---

Newest versions of Excel, formula<sup>‡</sup>:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(--TEXTSPLIT(B2," "),E$2:F$13,2,0))
```

<sup>‡</sup><sub>Ditch the double unary if you are actually working with string values.</sub>